# Ropsten: Sending a transaction from geth to metamask and metamask to geth

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

Starting I did this:

```
geth --testnet removedb
geth --testnet --rpc --fast --cache=1024
```

Using geth attach and looking at eth.syncing, I had currentBlock: 898328.  It stopped syncing there roughly and now eth.syncing is false.

Using Metamask I send a transaction to the same wallet geth is using.  Looking in geth with `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)` shows 0.  On etherscan I see transactions from Metamask, but not from geth.

Comment: You are connected to ropsten which has more than 2M blocks, if `eth.blockNumber` is not close to that number it means you are no fully synced. If `eth.syncing` returns false it means it has finished or it has lost connection to peers, check `admin.peers`. If after waiting some time it doesn't start to sync again, try restarting geth, it should use the default bootnodes.

Comment: Thanks, it's still doing some work, so hopefully it will finish.

Comment: It seemed to work, but I had to find a set of peers that had the correct head for the blockchain.  I now backed it up, so hopefully it will sync faster.